# Staying in Belgium as a Student

Tags: budget, study, belgium

I am interested in pursuing a masters programme in Belgium and one of the benefits of the scholarship I saw is an 860 euro allowance per month. I am wondering if anyone knows if this will be enough? i am from the Philippines and the cost of living here is different so I have no idea how far an 860 euro budget can go. by the way, the allowance will cover for food, public transport and personal expenses, excluding rent.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. Unfortunately, your question is off-topic here. First, questions about long-term stays are better suited to our sister site for [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/). Second, whether some amount of money is enough is impossible to say generically, because each person has different standards and lifestyle needs. Third, some parts of Belgium will be more expensive than others. There are online calculators as at [Expatistan](http://www.expatistan.com/cost-of-living) or [Numbeo](http://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/) that can help you make rough estimates.

Comment: 860 euro without rent? Easy. As a fellow student in Belgium I'll share you my expenses from last year. On average I paid about 500 euro/month. 250 for rent, 200 for food/drinks, 15 for phone, 35 for other expenses (I didn't do much though). Trains cost a maximum of 7.5 euro per drive and bus would be a euro per drive, but with that allowance, you could rent/buy a bike instead.

Answer (score 2):

For once, I think it's possible to give a general opinion. EUR 860 is slightly over the level of welfare benefits (*revenu d'intégration*) and it's lower than the minimal wage for full-time work (between EUR 1000 and EUR 1400 depending on age). Median (after-tax) wage is EUR 1800.

But rent is a big item so your allowance should provide a comfortable income if you don't have to pay for accommodation out of it.

Comment: The question said "excluding rent".

Comment: @PeterRaeves Precisely, otherwise my answer would make no sense…